# Как для datepicker установить + или - дату от выбранной на календаре, а не от сегодняшней?

Tags: javascript

Есть календарик datepicker. Нужно сохранить выбранную дату и другую (например -50d от ВЫБРАННОЙ).
Если делать:
$('#dateFirst')datepicker("setDate",-50d);

затем считать текущую, то получится -50 дней от сегодняшнего, а нужно -50 дней от выбранной.

Comment: Прибавляйте перед сохранением

Comment: поясните подробнее пожалуйста, что значит перед сохранением?